# Why is my NSMutableArray, located in a singleton, returning (null)?

Tags: objective-c, null, nsmutablearray, singleton, nsnumber

I am working in Xcode 4.5.1 in Objective-C. I’m making a hearing test and want to store relevant data to each question in an array. I made a singleton MyManager. I use this to store data.

It is working fine for simple int/float values etc., but I’m stuck trying to use NSMutableArray. I’m new to Objective-C, so I’m assuming/hoping I've made some obvious mistake.

So, I want to fill mySNRArray with float values. I’ve come to understand that I can’t simply add floats, because it will only take objects. Thus, I use NSNumber.

Problem: When I try to read the data that I’ve supposedly added to the NSMutableArray, I get (null).

I will now provide the relevant code:

MyManager.h

```
@interface MyManager : NSObject
{

NSMutableArray *mySNRArray;

}

@property (readwrite) NSMutableArray *mySNRArray;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

MyManager.m

```
@implementation MyManager

@synthesize mySNRArray;

+ (id)sharedManager
{
static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
    {

            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];

    });

return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init
{
if (self = [super init])
{

    NSMutableArray *mySNRArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}

return self;
}

@end
```

TestViewController.m

```
//First, I try to add a value to mySNRArray.

MyManager *Manager = [MyManager sharedManager];

NSNumber *tempStorage1 = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:mySNR];

[Manager.mySNRArray insertObject:tempStorage1 atIndex:questionNumber];

//The NSLog below is showing the correct value.

NSLog(@"%@ : mySNR", tempStorage1);


...


for (n = 0; n < questionNumber; n++)
{

//Second, I try to acces the values I supposedly added to mySNRArray. 

MyManager *Manager = [MyManager sharedManager];

//This NSLog below is showing (null).

NSLog(@"Value at %i in SNRArray = %@", n, [Manager.mySNRArray objectAtIndex:n]);

}


...
```

I hope somebody can explain my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
NSMutableArray *mySNRArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

to

```
self->_mySNRArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

in your init method you are creating a local mutable array, but not assigning it to your property

Comment: `self->_mySNRArray` is correct, but you can also drop `self->` and just use `_mySNRArray`.

Comment: +1 Also the use of `[NSMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:]` looks dodgy; `NSMutableArray` won't allow sparse arrays.

Comment: @BenedictCohen yeah thats just for style, but thought it might make this question clearer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new object, use the ivar you created..in the `init` method.

```
_mySNRArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Even you can ommit these, from your .h

```
{

NSMutableArray *mySNRArray;

}
```

Comment: This is the same answer that @wattson12 gave 7 minutes earlier?!?

Comment: I removed self-> and added {

NSMutableArray *mySNRArray;

}

Comment: Would omitting the declaration of `mySNRArray` work on a 32-bit OSX runtime?

Comment: So, you suggest in all the newer application we must use ivars and property both?  As he said  he is using xcode4.5.1 so I advised him he can do without that ivar.... And I dont know if his target is ppc!!!

Comment: Not if he's compiling for 32-bit OSX he can't (he doesn't specify what he's building for).  All those "time saving features" where you don't need to declare things will cost you maintenance time later anyway when you come back to the code and are confused where things are declared.  They are lazy and stupid.

Comment: Yes that I agree. But without the BRD, I guess anyone will be developing for future at least for 10.7...

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the OSX version or the Xcode version; the 32-bit (i386) runtime doesn't support many features including ARC, and those "no need to declare" features.  I would not recommend anyone use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (id)sharedManager
```

returns a value

```
static MyManager* sharedManager
```

Change the interface to

```
+ (MyManager*)sharedManager
```

and the compiler will tell you exactly what mistake you made.